# Twice Join in Symfony2 with Doctrine (Syntax Error)

Tags: php, symfony, join, doctrine-orm

I have the tables:

```
Car(Auto) ->(1:N) Rent (N:1) <- Department(Abteilung)
```

I want to join them with an inner join together. In Rent are the IDs of department and car.

If I do a join twice I get an error. With one join it's working. Why is that? How can i fix this?

```
$result = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('ChrisKfzBuchungBundle:Rent')
            ->createQueryBuilder('r')
            ->innerJoin('ChrisKfzBuchungBundle:Rent','ChrisKfzBuchungBundle:Auto')
            ->innerJoin('ChrisKfzBuchungBundle:Rent','ChrisKfzBuchungBundle:Abteilung')
            ->where('r.mieteStart >= :date_from')
            ->andWhere('r.mieteEnde <= :date_to')
            ->setParameter('date_from', $date_from)
            ->setParameter('date_to', $date_to)
            ->distinct()
            ->getQuery()->getArrayResult();
```

> [Syntax Error] line 0, col 129: Error: Expected Literal, got 'JOIN'

Thanks!

Comment: Try making the join like this:  `->innerJoin('r.auto', 'auto)` and `->innerJoin('r.abteilung', 'abteilung)`

Comment: Then there is no syntax error but i get NO result for the table 'abteilung'

Comment: this is because you are only selecting 'r' at `->createQueryBuilder('r')`

Comment: i testet it without joins, the joins are useless they don't give more data then without. whats that?

Comment: Of course, in your case, joins do nothing cause you are not retrieving data across them. In your query you only are `selection Rents where date is between`. Nothing more.

Comment: What information do you want to retrieve?

Answer (score 1):

That works, thanks to manix for help. I had to correct the Joins and use addSelect (an me unknown command).

```
 $result = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('ChrisKfzBuchungBundle:Rent')
            ->createQueryBuilder('r')
            ->addSelect('abteilung')
            ->addSelect('auto')
            ->join('r.auto','auto')
            ->join('r.abteilung','abteilung')
            ->where('r.mieteStart >= :date_from')
            ->andWhere('r.mieteEnde <= :date_to')
            ->setParameter('date_from', $date_from)
            ->setParameter('date_to', $date_to)
            ->distinct()
            ->getQuery()->getArrayResult();
```